# How to load a txt file from the same package

Tags: java, file-io

I have a package structure like `com/tcs/incubation/sml/crawler/mediasources/twitterriver`.
I have a txt file which i need to load from this package structure i.e.twitterriver.

I am able to access the file by adding src like 
`src/com/tcs/incubation/sml/crawler/mediasources/twitterriver` by

```
BufferedReader objBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
```

This filepath will contain the absolute path using `.getAbsolutePath()` method.

So how do i load my txt file from `com/tcs/incubation/sml/crawler/mediasources/twitterriver`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file belongs to the internals of your programm, just use `TwitterRiver.class.getRessourceAsStream()` to obtain a InputStream.

Comment: @saurabhj Yes, and you need to place the file you want to read at the same directory. Don't forget to package the resource file with your class files. Calling `getResourceAsStream()` is appropriate if your resource is some kind of static configuration file, that you will change only when you release a new version of your application.

Comment: when i use the code with the whole package InputStream inputStream=SMLTwitterRiverUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/‌​‌​tcs/incubation/sml/crawler/mediasources/twitterriver/CrawlingRiverIndexQuery.tx‌​t"‌​)); It works fine but when i use only the filename which is in the same package like –
InputStream inputStream=(SMLTwitterRiverUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("CrawlingRiverIndexQuery.txt"));
it gives a null pointer exception

Comment: @saurabhj with `class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)` the search starts at root. If you use `SMLTwitterRiverUtil.class.getResourceAsStream(...)` your file needs to be in the same folder as the class source/compiled class. It's ok and documented behaviour to use the absolute path with the first variant - if this is what you want.